# Error while giving more command related to ipv6table

Tags: linux-kernel

I am facing issue while giving command

```
ip6tables -A DDoS -j DROP
```

It is resulting in errors like

```
root@TimeProvider:~# ip6tables -A DDoS -j DROP 
ip6tables: Invalid argument. 
Run `dmesg' for more information. 
root@TimeProvider:~# dmesg|tail -n 20 ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): 
mgmt0: link is not ready 
mgmt0: Link is up - 1000/Full 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): 
mgmt0: link becomes ready TMAC switching to SyncE slave mode on PHY 0 TMAC switching to SyncE master mode on PHY 1 
mgmt0: no IPv6 routers present TMAC switching to SyncE slave mode on PHY 0 TMAC switching to SyncE master mode on PHY 1 
eth0: no IPv6 routers present 
eth1: no IPv6 routers present 
ip6_tables: limit match: invalid size 40 != 48
```

Is it a syntax error of the command or is it a system error?

Comment: Please format your question to be readable ...

Comment: this is system error actully what is happening that ip6table is 32 bit executable and kernel is 64 bit, so this problem is happening , can anyone help on that, what to resolve this issue.